# Inserting blank space to text inside span fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span element in my Dom like this

```
<span class="intro">Create your account inng to some worthy causes.</span>
```

I am trying to append a blank space after the last character inside that span
My code is like this

```
$($('.sp-pods h2 span')).each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + '&nbsp;');
});
```

Everything looks okay to me, But the blank space is not getting added. But if I try some thing like this

```
$($('.sp-pods h2 span')).each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + 'xx';');
});
```

It works well/ Only blank space is not coming. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `$($('.sp-pods h2 span'))` should be `$('.sp-pods h2 span')`

Comment: @madalinivascu you can give me a better way. I am all open to all suggestions

Comment: Try to use the CSS rules.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki can you please give an example as an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `padding-right` or `margin-right` like :

```
span.intro{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Or :

```
span.intro{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```css
span.intro{
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="intro">Create your account inng to some worthy causes.</span>TEXT AFTER SPACE
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use css pseudo elements for this.

```
.intro::after {
   content: ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
&nbsp; is not accepted.
```

you can simply add space into function you are calling

```
 $($('.sp-pods h2 span')).each(function () {

    $(this).text($(this).text() + ' ');
});
```

or you can replace   with '\u00a0'

```
 $($('.sp-pods h2 span')).each(function () {

$(this).text($(this).text() + '\u00a0');
```

});